# Typescript: Exclude undefined from union type

Tags: typescript

There is a custom type `Options`  (nested object) that I created. I want to use the type `DefaultProperties` to create an object that contains the default properties.

```
type Options = {
    id: number,
    text: string | undefined,
    properties: {
        title: string,
        subtitle: string | undefined,
    }
}

type DefaultProperties = Pick<Options, "properties">;
```

Of course the default properties cannot be `undefined`. So I want to exclude `undefined` from my union types.
For that purpose there *should be* a build-in functions like `NonNullable<T>` or `Exclude<T,UnionType>`.

I tried three different ways to remove `undefined` but no solution is working with my type.

```
type Options = {
    id: number,
    text: string | undefined,
    properties: {
        title: string,
        subtitle: string | undefined,
    }
}

type DefaultProperties = Pick<Options, "properties">;


// Try #1: does not work
type Type1 = NonNullable<DefaultProperties>;

// Try #2: does not work
type NotOptional<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type]-?: Type[Property];
};
type Type2 = NotOptional<DefaultProperties>;

// Try #3: does not work
type Type3 = Exclude<Options, undefined>;
```

**Example:** [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=42&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCkKgQBMAuKFAVwFsAjCAJwBoCjgIAPYCtYRhCgDmUAD5QqKEhABmgiCVZEoYRkkiNEENBXzLliYABsIvfoKFL9hNFTqGTZgcLESps%20YraEAvnj94oJBQACKyAIZURsAACmoaWhjYMQgAxgDWADxwiKhozFAARKrqTImFAHwA3Hi1APR1UAAqjCBQAMQAjBQkSNqUSMBQAO5IjOmB4NBNU51YUAByqAtRRuF0JplhMpHRcaWaCNrV9Y0tbe0ATD19GCiDI2MTQdBLwDnIKOFGmTOQFfM9EQANr7BJtQRQdIQEBIGTNKYAXQAtAB%20Ch-CCg%20JlECImo%20GovBGQS7zN4fVDfLYRKKxHGHY41PANZqtDoAZhu-XuQ1G40mwUxHPmAFFOKkjFRpNl4J98m5pHIUAoTnggA)

How can I remove all `undefined`s from all of my type union types?

**Edit:**
All `undefined`s should be removed from my type. For example:

- `Options['text'] : string` (No more `undefined`)
- `Options['properties']['subtitle'] : string` (No more `undefined`)

Later I want to use the type for this (for example):

```
const options : Options = { ... };
const defaults: DefaultProperties= { ... }; // With no undefined

const node : HTMLElement = .... ;
node.innerHTML = options.properties.subtitle !== undefined ? options.properties.subtitle : defaults.properties.subtitle;
```

When `defaults.properties.subtitle` has the type `string | undefined`, the compiler throws an error because `innerHTML` only allows `strings`. For that I want to exclude `undefined`.

Comment: `type NonNullable<T> = T extends undefined ? never: T;`

Comment: Compiler still says that `DefaultProperties['properties']['subtitle']` has the type `string | undefined`, but I want it to be from type `string`.

Comment: Try `text?: string`

Comment: The key should not be optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close with your `NotOptional` utility type and `Exclude`, the problem is that you're defining `DefaultProperties` as an object with a `properties` property, but you're trying to remove `undefined` from `DefaultProperties`, not from its `properties` property.

In a comment you've said you want `DefaultProperties` to be the same shape as `properties` on `Options`. That means the basic shape of it (before we try to remove `undefined`) is `Options["properties"]`. So:

```typescript
type NotOptional<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type]: Exclude<Type[Property], undefined>;
};

type DefaultProperties = NotOptional<Options["properties"]>;
```

Tests:

```typescript
const defaults1: DefaultProperties = {
    title: "foo",
    subtitle: undefined,    // <== Error as desired
};

const defaults2: DefaultProperties = {
    title: "foo",
    subtitle: "something",  // <== No error
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCkKgQBMAuKFAVwFsAjCAJwBoCjgIAPYCtYRhCgDmUAD5QqKEhABmgiCVZEoYRkkiNEENBXzLliYABsIvfoKFL9hNFTqGTZgcLESps+YraEAvnj94oJBQAHJIwHCIqACGRgA8ACrgEAB8WLjeUADaAApqGqDEKFAA1hAgSDJQSZAAuhQAopwAxkZU0onJuflMoLXMbtJyKAopANz+E4HJUAAistFURsB56r0I2ulhEfDIKLFxkXtoWQBEqmuaG2inteN4eM2ofFBDi8toAIwU8zLvKz0rptsHp2AhjKYoKcZEgkKcrDY7A5IZIhp4BkQAPSYqBxTDYBqMNSMKDRDDSNAIRgKSYPJ7oYCvBZLYBoABMP2Zy1WBWu6VBhGRFGhsPhmVs9nBjihaCQNAgwAAFhZ4YRsbj8aEkFAmMTJkA)

You might also consider removing optionality (combining two of the things you tried):

```typescript
type NotOptional<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type]-?: Exclude<Type[Property], undefined>;
};

type DefaultProperties = NotOptional<Options["properties"]>;
```

Tests:

```typescript
const defaults1: DefaultProperties = {
    title: "foo",
    subtitle: undefined,    // <== Error as desired (wrong type for `subtitle`)
};

const defaults2: DefaultProperties = {  // <== Error as desired (missing `somethingElse`)
    title: "foo",
    subtitle: "something",
};

const defaults3: DefaultProperties = {  // <== No error
    title: "foo",
    subtitle: "something",  // <== No error
    somethingElse: "x",
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCkKgQBMAuKFAVwFsAjCAJwBoCjgIAPYCtYRhCgDmUAD5QqKEhABmgiCVZEoYRkkiNEENBXzLliYABsIvfoKFL9hNFTqGTZgcLESps+YrbW0SGhGAACwsAUSM0CAB+JwsrQgBfPES8UEgoADkkYDhEVABDIwAeABVwCAA+LFxvKABtAAU1DVBiFCgAawgQJBkoUsgAXQBaaKgQzgBjIyppErKGpqZQAeY3aTkUBXKAbiTdlLKoABFZPKojYEb1JYRtKszs+GQUAsKc57RagCJVa81btBfAY7PB4CaoPhQdZnC5oACMFBOMhhl0W-zu2D07AQxlMUC+MiQSC+cSgtnsOMcaw8m0UygA9PSoIVMNgQow1IwoHkMNI0AhGAooAAKADuahcqWghK5AANyQ4ILKAJR7UHg9DAKGnc7ANAAJkROouV2aAKqOEIjOZrLGHKQXJ52v5gpIIpoCDQ-Jc8r8AWCwjCERVNUVFAJRJJNQVlLxX18-iCFij8X2Gsh0N1aAAzEbkbrTTcMbgrUyWdhMlAmJzQ7Hw4TiaSY7jwwn-cnVlBreWMkgq-bGNG-UnA+E45wU9sgA)

Comment: I want that `DefaultOptions` has the same shape as `Options[properties]`. When using `pick`, the key `properties` is also added. Dont know how to remove it, but the solution with the key `properties` works for me. @main problem: In both cases the compiler returns `string | undefined` for the key `subtitle`. This is the `undefined` I want to exclude. E.g. using it later: `document.querySelector('#n')!.innerHTML = options.properties.subtitle !== undefined : options.properties.subtitle : defaultOptions.properties.subtitle`. When defaultOptions.properties.subtitle is `string | undefined` error.

Comment: @michaelT - Sorry, I've messed up this answer two or three times now. I believe the current version actually does what you described (which wasn't unclear by the way, I just tested the first version incorrectly and then made a series of editing errors in the second version).